# What were the regimental colors of the 18th NY Infantry Regiment?

Tags: american-civil-war

Im desperatively searching for the regimental colors belonging to the 18th New York Volunteer Infantry Regiment, which fought on the Union side during the Maryland Campaign.

It's a relatively unpopular regiment which also hasn't a fancy story like the 10th Maine oder 69th NY, so it's quite hard to find any historical reference.

I've checked every reference I could find, but without result.

I hope some of you have some secret sources.

Why am I doing this? An ancestor of mine served in Company C and I'm interested in making a little report about this.

Edit: Or did they simply use the Union colors? As far as I'm concerned, the 98th NY Volunteers also used the Union flag, where the 11th or 149th had an own color.

Edit 2: If there's no picture, is it possible to find a description? Based on similar colors I could create a(n) (artistic) reconstruction

Comment: Call up the relevant army or national guard library and historian. You may need to comb the archives. US military heraldry could also be of use. You can find contacts for all of these online.

Comment: @StuartAllan Calling somewhere in the US will cost me a fortune, as I'm living in Germany. Also, my spoken English is terrible. But I'll write an e mail

Comment: If you get a good answer please remember to answer your own question.

Comment: There is a [website for the 18th New York Volunteer Infantry Regiment](https://www.18thnyi.com/), which includes a link to 'Contact Historian'.  This might be an alternative approach worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>   Im desperately searching for the regimental colors belonging to the 18th New York Volunteer Infantry Regiment, which fought on the Union side during the Maryland Campaign.
>
> Edit 2: If there's no picture, is it possible to find a description? Based on similar colors I could create a(n) (artistic) reconstruction

I couldn't find a picture for the 18th New York Volunteer Infantry Regiment.  But I found a description of regimental colors which would allow you to recreate their flag or a proximity of it.

During the civil war Regimental Colors referred to two flags afforded to each infantry regiment. a National Flag (stars and stripes) and regimental flag which was blue with gold lettering.  The descriptions and examples of both are given below along with sources.

> **[Regimental Colors](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/agency/army/regiment-civil-war-colors.htm)**
>   According to Civil War Army Regulations: "Each regiment of Infantry shall have two silken colors.
>
> **The first**, or the national color, of stars and stripes, as described for the garrison flag; the number and name of the regiment to be embroidered with silver on the center stripe.
>
> **The second**, or regimental color, to be blue, with the arms of the United States embroidered in silk on the center. The name of the regiment in a scroll, underneath the eagle. The size of each color to be six feet six inches fly, and six feet deep on the pike. The length of the pike, including the spear and ferrule, to be nine feet ten inches. The fringe yellow; cords and tassels, blue and white silk intermixed." After February 1862 also inscribed upon the colors of the regiment were the names of the battles in which the regiment "have borne a meritorious part."

**Examples of Regimental Colors**

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Sources:**

-**[Regimental Colors & Flags of the Union Army  •  1861-65](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/agency/army/regiment-civil-war-colors.htm)**